# Mysql and php query into another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I've a big problem and reading in the web maybe i've found the solution but the logic of it, is too difficult to understand i think :)

I've a table in my mysql database and here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE eventi (
id INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
autore VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
tipo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
titolo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
contenuto VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
data_evento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
fine_evento VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
data_finale VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
ora_evento VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
ora_fevento VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
img VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
accessi int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
pagato SET(  '0',  '1' ) NOT NULL default '0',
pacchetto SET(  '1',  '2', '3' ) DEFAULT NULL , -- Offerta 1=7gg, 2=14gg, 3=31gg
data DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Ok, the problem is this:

I sell to my clients an events and they pay more or less if they use a type of "pacchetto".
You can see from the table that there is a column called "pacchetto" (packet) which could be set to 1, 2 or 3. If they select the first (1), their event will be displayed 7 days before the date (that is "data_finale" - in english: last_date); if they select the second (2), 14 days, and the third (3), 31 days.
I've lot of clients and if a client have selected the packet 1 and the event should be online and another client have selected the packet 3 and the event should be online, i have to show both events of both clients.
I think its "difficult" however i've done this, but seems dont run, it show me only 1 right event:
    pastebin . com / RscmQJ7L
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: pastebin.com/RscmQJ7L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to re-write your SQL query. All can be done in 1 query which is much more performant. Just concat your conditions with OR like this:

```
... WHERE (pacchetto = '1' AND (data_finale >= NOW() AND data_finale <= (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)) OR
pacchetto = '2' AND (data_finale >= NOW() AND data_finale <= (NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY)) OR
pacchetto = '3' AND (data_finale >= NOW() AND data_finale <= (NOW() + INTERVAL 31 DAY))
```

Not tested but you should get the idea.

Comment: I've modified: http://pastebin.com/tgcxAyz5
but it gives me an error: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/htdocs/www.worfut.it/home/mainevents.php on line 48 Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/htdocs/www.worfut.it/home/mainevents.php on line 54
and the line 54 is the line 11 in the link i've gave to you

Comment: You missed a ) off the end. WHERE (pacchetto = '1' AND (data_finale >= NOW() AND data_finale <= (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)) OR
pacchetto = '2' AND (data_finale >= NOW() AND data_finale <= (NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY)) OR
pacchetto = '3' AND (data_finale >= NOW() AND data_finale <= (NOW() + INTERVAL 31 DAY)))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar similar issue when doing a mysql_query within a mysql_fetch.  Best avoided.  Either do within one SQL statement or bring back query in to an array and then traverse the array.  Also, mysql_query is best avoided. Yo should use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: i dont know how to use mysqli or pdo and i've no time to learn it :(